# Get documents By ID from document library using Rest API

Tags: 2013, document-library, rest

## Scenario

I have a Document library named "My Documents". In that library couple of folders, for these each folders have another couple of folders (subfolders) and inside these folders, certain documents. Requirements are that all these document id must be unique.

Now if I have the document id. How to get perticular document from its id? When the document is found I want the path to that document.

How do I accomplish that using Rest API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally i found solution, i got full file url through **EncodedAbsUrl**

My Document id is 6 and got full filepath from its id

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
             "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('My Documents')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=Id eq 6";


var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    {        
       $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
            var path = result.EncodedAbsUrl;
         });

    },
    error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving document(s) by ID, the best approach is to use filter parameter from [MS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests).

Example:

```
<url_SP_Site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[Name_Document_Library]')/items?$select=Id&$filter=Id eq '[Id_you_search_for]'
```

If you want to search for multiple documents IDs, you can add `and` or `or` operators (I think you have more operators, see the documentation).

Examples:

```
<url_SP_Site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[Name_Document_Library]')/items?$select=Id&$filter=Id eq '[Id_you_search_for]' and Id eq '[Another_Id_you_search_for]'
```

```
<url_SP_Site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[Name_Document_Library]')/items?$select=Id&$filter=Id eq '[Id_you_search_for]' or Id eq '[Another_Id_you_search_for]'
```

After that you can use expand parameter with file value to have the relative URL:

```
[url_SP_Site]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('[Name_Document_Library]')/items?$select=Id,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File&$filter=Id eq '[Id_you_search_for]' or Id eq '[Another_Id_you_search_for]'
```

When you get the response encoded in JSON Format, you can access easily with:

```
d/results([Your_Index])/File/ServerRelativeUrl
```