# How to retrieve a SharePoint list item using document ID only

Tags: development, rest

How can I retrieve a SharePoint list item using just the document ID? I am accessing a SharePoint 2013 server (with document IDs enabled) remotely from a .NET application. I do not know which site or library the item exists in...only have the document ID. I would like to use the SharePoint REST service if possible although I will consider any solution that works.

I've tried using the following URLs, but the results always contain 0 items:

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='ABC-19-29575'
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='docid:ABC-19-29575'
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='documentid:ABC-19-29575'
```

Comment: Looks similar to a question that has been answered before: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86067/get-documents-by-id-from-document-library-using-rest-api

Comment: But in that question, the user knew the library.

Comment: You need to make sure the managed property DocID is queryable.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this yet? I have the same issue. If you have any answer, please post it. Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did sort of find a solution to this issue. What I ended up doing was to create an HttpWebRequest to the Doc ID URL and retrieve the HTTP headers. I had to disable AllowAutoRedirect so I could get the "Location" header which contained the path I was looking for. Sometimes this would not always work and I would need to create another HttpWebRequest to the redirected URL where I use RegEx to extract the path contained within the XML.

Answer (score 2):

I have it turned on as a column in one of my views the address follows this

```
/managedpath/sitecollection/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=ABC-19-29575
```

Don't know how that converts to REST or if it will work if you don't know the site collection.

In search schema the managed property name is **dlcDocIdOWSTEXT**. There is another managed property called DocId, but that is a completely different value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the Document ID site collection feature enabled for
   the relevant site collection(s).

**NOTE**:  For existing documents, you will have to wait until the timer job runs after the feature has been enabled - before you will see document ID's.

2. Create a searchable, filterable, & query-able managed property mapped to the crawled property titled: "ows__dlc_docid".  See [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/search-by-document-id-in-sharepoint/8f988930-03a4-467c-9592-0c1d0eae33c4) for details/screenshots.
   Once your content has been crawled after the document ID assignment and managed property creation, you should see results via the search interface or API using the following:

> [Managed Property Name]:ZMHZ4F7HWUFU-281895529-13

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I found it while I was struggling with the same issue... According to https://www.petri.com/using-document-ids-sharepoint-online you can use DlcDocId to query by Document Id. I use it in the CSOM like

```
var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(ctx);
keywordQuery.QueryText = "DlcDocId:FF6CNQQPKMYZ-371695361-1";
```

and it's working fine!