# getting the file template used for a specific file in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-document-library

I am trying to not have to create a different content type for a document library. Instead I was thinking if given the files in a document library I can find out which file template was used for that document.

Is there such thing? Can I query it with JavaScript/SPFX webpart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever is looking for the same. You can achieve by expanding the ContentType of the the file. here is the api path:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Success%20Stories')/Items?$select=ContentType/DocumentTemplate&$expand=ContentType
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below REST API code to read the specific file from SharePoint:

```
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
             "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('My Documents')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=Id eq 6";


var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    {        
       $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
            var path = result.EncodedAbsUrl;
            var fileTemplate= result.Template;

         });

    },
    error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});
```

**Note**:

- var path = result.EncodedAbsUrl; - This gives the absolute URL of the file
- now type **result.Template** which will give the template name - may be the exact template attribute name will be different, then in the debug mode (F12) after **result.**
  type "Templ" - then we will get the exact attribute name.

Reference:

[Get documents By ID from document library using Rest API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86067/get-documents-by-id-from-document-library-using-rest-api)

Comment: Thanks, Although that does not quite answer the question, there is not such a name and you just showing how to query a document library, we need to expand the content type. 

I am posting a separated for the sake of clarity.